# How to use move_base?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this one very useful http://wiki.ros.org/move_base, but I have no idea how can I apply it to use in my project like how to install, what command to use and so on. Could anyone help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200371/how-to-use-move_base?/) by [newcastle](https://answers.ros.org/users/21270/newcastle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you do the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2